# TypeError: Cannot read property 'jwtToken' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to develop an authentication system for my ionic application.
When I try to open the password recovery page of my application it shows me this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'jwtToken' of undefined

[image: Error]

This is part of my securityService

> `angular
>       .module('starter')
>       .factory('securityService', securityService);

```
/*@ngInject*/
function securityService($rootScope, config, cooperons, common, jwtHelper, securityRepository) {

    return {
        saveAuthenticationToken: saveAuthenticationToken,
        refreshToken: refreshToken,
        loadSession: loadSession,
        checkSecurity: checkSecurity,
        hasRole: hasRole,
        isGranted: isGranted,
        setConnectAsMember: setConnectAsMember,
        finishConnectAsMember: finishConnectAsMember,
        dispatch: dispatch,
        logout: logout
    };

    /**
     * @ngdoc method
     * @name saveAuthenticationToken
     * @methodOf core.services:common
     * @description Save token of authenticated user
     *
     * @param {object} data Contain token and refresh token of member
     */
    function saveAuthenticationToken(data) {
        common.clearStoredItems();
        common.storeItem(cooperons.storedKeys.jwtToken, data.token);
        common.storeItem(cooperons.storedKeys.jwtRefreshToken, data.refresh_token);
        loadSession();
    }

    /**
     * @ngdoc method
     * @name loadSession
     * @methodOf core.services:common
     * @description Load user session from local storage
     */
    function loadSession() {
        $rootScope.auth = null;
        var jwtToken = common.getStoredItem(cooperons.storedKeys.jwtToken);
        var jwtRefreshToken = common.getStoredItem(cooperons.storedKeys.jwtRefreshToken);
        if (jwtToken) {
            try {
                var tokenData = jwtHelper.decodeToken(jwtToken);
                $rootScope.auth = {
                    token: jwtToken,
                    refreshToken: jwtRefreshToken,
                    roles: tokenData.roles,
                    username: tokenData.username,
                    connectAsMember: common.getStoredItem(cooperons.storedKeys.connectAsMember)
                };
            } catch (err) {
                logout();
            }
        }

        return $rootScope.auth;
    }
```

`

Comment: Showing relevant parts of `securityService` code would be helpful, you know.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide some codes so you may get help.

Comment: @raina77ow  I modified my question and added some code

Comment: it seems there is issue with `cooperons` service(providing code snippet would help to narrow it to issue). maybe  you are not returning the `storedKeys` property from your factory or u forgot to define(or u forgot to make it public property) in your service!